# In what instances does Community♦ dupe-hammer a question?

Tags: support, dupehammer, community-user

I saw a [question in my feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37185208/why-are-math-floor-and-math-ceiling-doubles) that was a duplicate; I flagged it as such and the question was closed a moment later:

[image]

Notice that the question was closed as a duplicate by three users: two normal users and the Community♦ user (diamond mod privileges meant that Community's vote was binding).

I haven't seen the Community♦ user use Mjölnir to dupe-hammer a question in this way before; **in what instances does Community♦ dupe-hammer a question?**

A couple of things that I can think of:

- An algorithm determined that the two questions were asking exactly the same thing;
- Community♦ automatically dupe-hammers if a question receives many duplicate flags/votes in a short space of time

Comment: The OP agreed with the dupe vote. They get a dialog offering the close vote.

Comment: @rene Makes sense, maybe write that as an answer and I'll accept. I find it strange that this hasn't been asked on Meta before, but there's always a first time for everything.

Comment: Now that it's closed, this post is as meta as it gets.

Comment: @AndrasDeak METAAAAA! Anyhow, it'll make the answer easier to locate now.

Comment: @cybermonkey indeed, "dupe" is an important keyword missing from the target, but present in this post --> +1

Comment: Community has dupe hammered your question about community dupe hammering questions on meta... Omg were so meta right now.

Comment: You can see how it works by hovering over Community's username. Not the most intuitive way to discover that.